# Azure AD Authentication from ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, adal

I am struggling to find if I can authenticate my users with Azure AD using ADAL in a MVC Web Application directly.

I have the application setup and working. When a user hits a page requiring authorization it redirects to MS to login, then redirects back just fine. I need to host the login form.

Is this supported? I find a lot of misleading information and no definitive documentation or examples.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you want to host the form yourself?

Comment: I need to abstract the authentication provider from my end users, while still using the benefits of cloud based AD. Also to not have to have end users supply the username in email form. Ex. jsmith vs jsmith@somedomain.com.